# how to put a private use character in string with xamarin

Tags: c#, fonts, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to use some icons from the metro font (http://metroui.org.ua/font.html) on my Xamarin project, I can't find a solution to put a character in private use on my string, it's always replace by a square with a `?` inside.

If anyone know how I can put special character, it could really help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom renderer for this in Android. The rest should work out of the box. [This example](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31530/fontawesome-label-heres-how) makes use of FontAwesome, but should work with yours as well.

First lets make sure your font is included the right way.

In case of Android you will need to put the font in your Assets folder and mark it as a `BundleAsset`.

In case of iOS copy it to the Resources folder and mark it as `BundleResource` and set it to 'Copy Always'. Lastly edit the **info.plist** and add

```
 <key>UIAppFonts</key>
 <array>
   <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Then the custom renderer for Android will look something like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FontAwesomeIcon), typeof(FontAwesomeIconRenderer))]

namespace AAA.Android.Renderers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the FontAwesome.ttf to the Assets folder and mark as "Android Asset"
    /// </summary>
   public  class FontAwesomeIconRenderer: LabelRenderer
    {
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           if (e.OldElement == null)
           {
               //The ttf in /Assets is CaseSensitive, so name it FontAwesome.ttf
               Control.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, FontAwesomeIcon.Typeface + ".ttf");
           }
       }
    }
}
```

And here is a custom Label implementation for it:

```
namespace AAA.Common.Views.Shared.FontAwesome
{
    public class FontAwesomeIcon : Label
    {
        //Must match the exact "Name" of the font which you can get by double clicking the TTF in Windows
        public const string Typeface = "FontAwesome";  

        public FontAwesomeIcon(string fontAwesomeIcon=null)
        {
            FontFamily = Typeface;    //iOS is happy with this, Android needs a renderer to add ".ttf"
            Text = fontAwesomeIcon;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get more icons from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/
        /// Tip: Just copy and past the icon picture here to get the icon
        /// </summary>
        public static class Icon
        {
            public static readonly string Gear = "";
            public static readonly string Globe = "";
        }
    }
}
```

In the static class `Icon` you can add the icons you want to use.
Also [here](https://github.com/neilkennedy/FontAwesome.Xamarin/blob/master/FontAwesome.Xamarin/FontAwesome.cs) you can find a list of ascii codes, instead of the weird question mark icons.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Gerald, but it seems to be the solution in xamarin.forms? Isn't it? And the special characters like "" can't be copy in visual studio, it's always replace by a square with a "?". Do I have to change the encoding of my cs file?